# GeoFire - How to set security rule such that the geofire location is only writeable to the auth user?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, geofire

So I have a geofire data structure shown in the picture below. Each of my geofire location represents the location of where a photo was taken. So the unique key circled in red is the key that corresponds to a photo, saved in a separate branch in my database.

[image]

I am stuck now because I'm not sure how I can set my security rule allow write only if: "the authenticated user equals to the user that the photo belongs to".

Note: I cannot do the following,

```
image_location
 -public
  -user id
   -picture id
     - g: 
     - l:
        -0:
        -1:
```

This is because I need all image locations to be saved under 1 branch, so that the image can be directly queried by all users, as such:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
.child(image_location)
.child(public);
GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: it's been a long while since I developed against geoFire but as I recall, I used it to read from, i.e. you _get_ from geoFire, you don't write to it. ...right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, I am actually not aware of that. I don't actually plan to write , as in update the geoFire. The only thing I will do is delete it, but I thought you need write to be true to allow delete? Or is that not so?

Comment: check this out https://github.com/rhroyston/getaa.org/blob/master/public/js/script.js#L539

Comment: @RonRoyston Sorry, I might be missing something. But think you might've miss understood me. I don't have trouble querying my GeoFire. Just trying to figure out how to do the security rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geofire for JavaScript associates a location with a key. Beyond those two bits of information, it keeps no additional properties in the location.

This means that the only way to do something based on the current user, is if you use that user's UID as the key. You'd secure that with:

```
"image_locations": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
  }
}
```

Since you want to allow multiple photo's, this won't be possible. GeoFire for Java recently added the ability to add more data (such as your need for a UID) to the geo-locations, but that didn't happen in the JavaScript library yet.

Comment: "GeoFire for Java recently added the ability to add more data (such as your need for a UID) to the geo-locations" Wait, that will solve my problem wouldn't it? Since I'm using Java for android, I will be able to add additional data to the geofire object. I'm looking through the GeoFire documenation for Java right now, I haven't found that part about adding additional data to the geofire object yet.

Comment: Oh wait, I completely misread the code in your question. Indeed, the Java version has this ability now. I haven't used it myself, but it should allow what you need.

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to figure out that feature, but it should solve my problem. Really appreciate your help! Also, your firebase lessons on udacity were amazing, thank you for that too!

Answer (score 0):

[Understand Firebase Realtime Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). Here is how to do that. That write rule in particular. ...In your case the branch will not be `db("users")`, it will be whatever you've named it...

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```